# Downloading files using 'wget ' in centos 6 server takes a long time

Tags: virtual-machine, ftp, centos-6, centos6.5

I have two differents servers (Centos 6) with the same configuration , when I try to download files using " wget ", it takes a long time (speed less than 400k/s) on the first  server , but the second one  it's really very quick !.
I tried to disable IPV6 but nothing happenns.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Are those servers on the same network?

Comment: yes ! I'm using the network

Comment: the same* network !